# The signature of the matrix $S^tAS$ where $S$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix with coefficient $\mathbb{R}$ and $S$ be a nonsingular matrix. Then does the signature of $S^tAS$ equal that of $A$?

Comment: yes. It is more or less obvious depending on how you define the signature. What is your definition ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is true since A and S^tAS are [**congruent matrices**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence) and [**Sylvester's law of inertia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia) states that two congruent symmetric matrices with real entries have the same numbers of positive, negative, and zero eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

The key facts here are:

1. Every symmetric matrix exhibit orthogonal basis.
2. Using that basis we can diagonalize symmetric matrix using orthogonal matrix formed by orthogonal basis.
3. For orthogonal matrix inverse is equal to transpose for matrix.
4. After diagonalization eigenvalue of A are occur at diagonal position of $ S^tAS $ and all other elements are 0.
5. signature is number of positive value - number of negative value.